# Terraform state file on cloud creating/deleting vm

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

If I have 15 VMS deployed on the cloud, and I want to create one VM using terraform to test it and I want to delete the one VM. Would my state file include all 16 VMs or just one VM?

What's the best course of action to remove the VM?

- the state file only has one VM, run terraform destroy
- delete state file
- the state file has 16 VMS, run terraform destroy
- go to cloud console, delete VM and run terraform apply

Comment: I also noticed that all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't know this feature! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 15 VMs are already running and not managed by your TF code, then your TF state file would **only have one VM** (the 16th). Then to delete it, there are two options:

1. If your TF code does not include anything other resources, run `terraform destroy`
2. Delete the VM code from TF file, and run `terraform apply`